# Vue: Setting data from binded prop is using the default value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

When I pass in `name` as a prop, it works as expected and sets the `nameData` data field so that I can change it within the component.

**Parent**

```
<child name="charles"></child>
```

**Child**

```
data() {
    return {
        nameData: this.name
    }
},
props: {
     name: {type: String, default: "NONE"}
}
```

When I bind the prop like below, the `nameData` data field is set to the default prop, which is "None".  Why is that?

**Parent**

```
data() {
   return {
      firstName: "Charles"
  }
}

<child :name="firstName"></child>
```

**Child**

```
data() {
    return {
        nameData: this.name
    }
},
props: {
     name: {type: String, default: "NONE"}
}
```

Comment: Remember, the `data` function is executed only once, when the component is created. At that time, component wont have any data bindings(it is not yet mounted, it is being created). That time, `this.name` will be having default value. Then, after everything your prop will have correct value, but then you are not watching and updating it to `nameData` right? You don't set `nameData` in the `data` function. it is useless. You need to write a watcher for your prop and update `nameData` from there.

Comment: @MatJ If I am not mistaken, the props get populated first, so that they are available to everything including data section too. And "mounting" refers to inserting the whole thing into the page.

Comment: @curveball is right. You can use `props` to initialize `data`. But of course any future change to the prop value will not affect child's component data....

Comment: so to be clear:  it's just best always then to pass an event up to the parent, change the `data` there, and then the props passed down will reflect that

Comment: @MargieFowle3 kind of. But remember, that data in `data` section will not react to updates from the parent. You have to use `props` directly or `computed` if you wish to play with data somehow. Check my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

See my example

1. First child component works as expected (your code)
2. Second displays "NONE" because it's data is initialized with prop value, which is `undefined`  at the time the (child's) `data()` is executed. Any change to the prop in the future (in `mounted` in my example) wont affect child's data...

```js
const child = Vue.component('child', {
  data() {
    return {
      nameData: this.name
    }
  },
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "NONE"
    }
  },
  template: `<div> {{ nameData }} </div>`
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    child
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: "Charles",
      secondName: undefined
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.secondName = "Fred"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child :name="firstName"></child>
  <child :name="secondName"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: he implies that he has set `firstName: "Charles"` from the start, but in such a case it should have worked. I think that he really sets it somehow later as you showed in your example.

Answer (score 0):

`name="charles"` - you passed down the string "charles";

`:name="firstName"` - you passed down a variable "firstName" which seems to be undefined in the parent component at the time of child rendering and the prop in the child component gets the default value you provided it with.

**UPD**: I played a little with Michal's example. You can use `computed` instead of `data() {}` or directly a prop itself if you don't need any data transformation. Because it seems that you assign parent's `firstName` value in async mode or just later.

```js
const child = Vue.component('child', {
  computed: {
      nameData() {
          return this.name;
      }
  },
  props: {
    name: {
      type: String,
      default: "NONE"
    }
  },
  template: `<div> {{ nameData }} </div>`
})

const vm = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: {
    child
  },
  data() {
    return {
      firstName: "Charles",
      secondName: undefined
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.secondName = "Fred"
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child :name="firstName"></child>
  <child :name="secondName"></child>
</div>
```

Comment: It's coming from the initial data which i didn't bother to add ..I assumed it'd be clear but I guess not, sorry.  Just added it

Comment: @MargieFowle3 I reproduced your setup in Vue 2.6.11. It works. Try to check whether you have some watchers mutating the parent value or another data/props/computed section that might override initial one - something like that.

Comment: @MargieFowle3 or maybe you really set parent's value in async mode later on as Michal shows in his example above.

Comment: @curveball You dont need `computed` for that. Just use prop directly inside the child...

Comment: @MichalLevý yes, but he has a different name like `nameData` so if he wants to preserve it or transform the value somehow...